# How do I enable battery saver in Windows 10 with a batch file?

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, battery, battery-life

I change between power plans a lot on my laptop (Win10 Pro) so to eliminate clicks, I've been doing this via a simple batch file. For example, to enable my power saver power plan, I use:

```
@echo off
powercfg -s a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
```

This works fine, but the setting I'm trying to access is this one:

[image: battery saver setting]

When I change plans, this battery saver setting always defaults to off. Is there a way I can turn on battery saver via my batch file?

Thanks!